# TypeError: Cannot delete "value" property because configurable is false. (app_storefront_base/cartridge/scripts/formErrors.js#44)

Tags: login, login-errors

While adding information on customer registration page on the SFCC as a customer facing an issue as below:

```
TypeError: Cannot delete "value" property because configurable is false. (app_storefront_base/cartridge/scripts/formErrors.js#44)
```

[image]

Comment: In the 21.2 compatibility mode some new ES6 features were introduced. It might be related to those changes. Did you test your code in 19.10 version?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Just started encountering the same issue